# Python building JSON

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe (Shown as sample input) from this dataframe i want to generate sample output json (Shown below as Sample Expected Output).

One way i found is like i can convert dataframe into list of dictionaries and put parse logic but here problem is df having lots of data so if i am going to iterate and getting keys, values etc it is going to degrade performance.

Other way i am thinking through Pandas...Not sure how to do but i am guessing performance will be faster as compare to iterate and put logic.

Can anybody give me some idea how we can do it through Pandas?

**Sample Input:**

```
     biweekly  daily  index  monthly state      timestamp         type  weekly
0        61      2      0       90    MS  1487548800000   type_first      18
1         2      2      1        6    AL  1487548800000  type_second       2
2         0      0      2       23    AL  1487548800000   type_third       0
3        18      0      3       45    SC  1487548800000    type_four       2
```

**Sample Expected Output:**

```
{
    "period": {
        "weekly": {
            "state": [{
                "name": "MS",
                "type_first": 18
            },
            {
                "name": "AL",
                "type_second": 2,
                "type_third" : 0
            },
            {
                "name": "SC",
                "type_four": 2
            }]
        },
        "monthly": {
            "state": [{
                "name": "MS",
                "type_first": 90
            },
            {
                "name": "AL",
                "type_second": 6,
                "type_third" : 23
            },
            {
                "name": "SC",
                "type_four": 45
            }]
        },
        "biweekly": {
            "state": [{
                "name": "MS",
                "type_first": 31
            },
            {
                "name": "AL",
                "type_second": 2,
                "type_third" : 0
            },
            {
                "name": "SC",
                "type_four": 18
            }]
        },
        "daily": {
            "state": [{
                "name": "MS",
                "type_first": 2
            },
            {
                "name": "AL",
                "type_second": 2,
                "type_third" : 0
            },
            {
                "name": "SC",
                "type_four": 0
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Sumit

Comment: any code I wrote so far? Please provide us with your code.

Comment: @AlexFung Hey Whatever i tried is not working ...that's why i didn't put it.

Comment: There is no straight forward way to achieve what you need. `.groupby` is your friend.